# How to avoid "no-promise-executor-return" in this situation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

code:

```js
export function sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Docs link:
[no-promise-executor-return](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-promise-executor-return)

I have tried in many ways to avoid this error.
Unfortunately, to no avail.

Comment: ... _what_ ways? Your executor callback returns the value setTimeout returns to it due to the arrow function shorthand, so if you don't want it to return a value you could _not_ use that shorthand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an arrow function thing. `() => 0` is the same as `function() { return 0 }`. So your promise executor *does* return the response of `setTimeout`. In order to avoid this wrap the `setTimeout` call in a function body. (`() => { setTimeout(...) }`).